# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape None

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, theano, spyder

first of all , i search all solutions and i try this answer , but all is not working. So , i'm working deep learning and have a 3 classes , first cat , second dog , thirt human. I want to feeding own deep learning project. But i'm always see this error : ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_6_input to have shape (None, 200, 200, 1) but got array with shape (205, 1, 200, 200) . When i was change this code :

```
model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv , nb_conv) , 
                        activation = 'relu' , 
                        input_shape=(X_train.shape)))
```

I'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_8: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

If i'm dont change this code , and write this

```
model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv , nb_conv) , 
                        activation = 'relu' , 
                        input_shape=(200,200,1)))
```

is not problem but now model.fit getting this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_6_input to have shape (None, 200, 200, 1) but got array with shape (205, 1, 200, 200).
```

All project code is below. So thnx for all answer.

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD,RMSprop,adam
from keras.utils import np_utils

#   import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib
from numpy import * 
#SKLEARN
#   from sklearn.utils import shuffle 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 
import theano


#____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
import os

non_converted_image_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Oğuzhan\\Desktop\\DeepLearningProject\\mnist\\data\\input_data'
converted_image_file_path = 'C:\\Humansdataresized'

#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
from numpy import size

list_non_converted_images = os.listdir(non_converted_image_file_path) 
number_of_non_converted_images = size(list_non_converted_images)

#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
from PIL import Image

img_rows , img_cols = 200 , 200

for file in list_non_converted_images:
    imop = Image.open(non_converted_image_file_path + '\\' + file)
    img = imop.resize((img_rows,img_cols))
    gray= img.convert('L')
        #When translating a color image to black and white (mode “L”), the library uses the ITU-R 601-2 luma transform:
        #L = R * 299/1000 + G * 587/1000 + B * 114/1000
    gray.save(converted_image_file_path +'\\'+ file, "JPEG")
    #-- file , img , img_cols, img_rows , imop , gray
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
list_of_converted_images = os.listdir(converted_image_file_path)
number_of_converted_images = size(list_of_converted_images)

if (number_of_converted_images != number_of_non_converted_images):
    print('NON EUQALS ' , number_of_converted_images , " = " , number_of_non_converted_images)
    raise SystemExit
else:
    print('EQUALS ' , number_of_converted_images , " = " , number_of_non_converted_images)
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
import numpy as np

imatrix = np.array([np.array(Image.open(converted_image_file_path+ '\\'+ im2)).flatten() for im2 in list_of_converted_images], 'f')

label = np.ones((number_of_non_converted_images,),dtype=int)
label[0:84] = 0 #cat
label[85:170] = 1 #kopek
label[170:] = 2 #human 

#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
from sklearn.utils import shuffle 

shuffle_imatrix , shuffle_label = shuffle(imatrix,label,random_state=2) #shuffle_imatrix=data , shuffle_label = Label
train_data = [shuffle_imatrix,shuffle_label]

"""
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
img = imatrix[167].reshape(img_rows,img_cols)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
"""
print ("train data array[0] , train values : \n" ,train_data[0] , "\n")
print ("train data array[0] , shape train values : \n " ,train_data[0].shape ,"\n")

print ("train data array[1] , label values : \n" ,train_data[1] , "\n")
print ("train data array[1] , shape label values :\n ", train_data[1].shape, "\n")
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________!TAMAM!
batch_size = 32 #batch size to train 
nb_classes = 3 # we have 3 class in non processing data folder. first of cat , second dog , thirt people.
nb_epoch = 20 # number of epoch to train 

img_rows , img_cols = 200, 200

img_channels = 1
nb_filters = 32 #convolutional filter 
nb_pool = 2 #pooling
nb_conv = 3 #conv.
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 

X_data_set , y_label_set = (train_data[0],train_data[1]) #train_data[0] = shuffle_imatrix , train_data[1] = shuffle_label

X_train, X_test, y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X_data_set , y_label_set , test_size=0.2 , random_state=4)

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1 , img_rows , img_cols)#X_train.shape[0] = number of trained data , 1 = siyah beyaz olduğu için tek resim kanalı
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1 , img_rows, img_cols)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255 

print('X_train shape :', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0] , 'train samples' )
print(X_test.shape[0] , 'test samples') 

from keras import utils
from keras.utils import np_utils

#Convert class vectors to binary class matrices 
Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train , nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test , nb_classes)

i=100 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.imshow(X_train[i , 0] , interpolation='nearest')
print("label : " , Y_train[i,:])
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D

model = Sequential()

from keras.layers import Conv2D

model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv , nb_conv) , 
                        activation = 'relu' , 
                        input_shape=(X_train.shape)))


model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters, (nb_conv , nb_conv) , 
                        activation = 'relu'))


model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(nb_pool, nb_pool)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adadelta')
#_____________________________+________________________________________________________________________________________

model.fit(X_train , Y_train , batch_size = batch_size , nb_epoch = nb_epoch ,
           verbose = 1 , validation_data=(X_test , y_test))

model.fit(X_train, Y_train , batch_size=batch_size , nb_epoch = nb_epoch,
          verbose = 1 , validation_split = 0.2 )
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
score=model.evaluate(X_test , show_accuracy = True , verbose = 0)
print('Test score : ' , score[0])
print('Test accuracy : ' , score[1])
print(model.predict_classes(X_test[1:5]))
print(Y_test[1:5])
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
#%% 

#visualizing intermediate Layers

output_layer = model.layers[0].get_output()
output_fn = theano.function([model.layers[0].get])
#_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

input_image= X_train[0:1,:,:,:]
print(input_image.shape)

plt.imshow(input_image[0,0,:,:], cmap='gray')
plt.imshow(input_image[0,0,:,:])

output_image = output_fn(input_image)
print(output_image.shape)

# Rearrnge dimension so we can plot the result as RGB images
output_image = np.rollaxis(np.rollaxis(output_image , 3 , 1) , 3 , 1)
print(output_image.shape)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
for i in range(32):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(6, 6, i+1)
    #♠ax.imshow(output_image[0,:,:,i],interpolation='nearest') 
    ax.imshow(output_image[0,:,:,i],cmap=matplotlib.cm.gray)
    plt.xticks(np.array([]))
    plt.yticks(np.array([]))
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Try: `input_shape=(X_train.shape)[1:]`

Comment: thnx but i'm getting this error :

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_9/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,200,200], [3,3,200,32].

Comment: Try to delete lines where your reshape `x_train` and `x_test`

Comment: i'm deleted this 2 reshape rows , '#X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1 , img_rows , img_cols)#X_train.shape[0] = number of trained data , 1 = siyah beyaz olduğu için tek resim kanalı
#X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1 , img_rows, img_cols)' 

and try running , but now getting this error : 

'ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_11: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2'

Comment: Ok - so try to reshape like this: `X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)`

Comment: okey it's work , but now model.fit getting this error : ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_6 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (52, 1) , omg i'm crying :'(

Comment: Change `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_8 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (205, 3)`  same error.

Comment: From which line this error comes?

Comment: Sequantial model , conv2d , conv2d , max pooling etc. steps is okey. Error comes this line `model.fit(X_train , Y_train , batch_size = batch_size , nb_epoch = nb_epoch ,
           verbose = 1 , validation_data=(X_test , y_test))`

Comment: Could you print out shape of all xs and ys?

Comment: `X_train.shape
Out[47]: (205, 200, 200, 1)

X_test.shape
Out[48]: (52, 200, 200, 1)

Y_train.shape
Out[49]: (205, 3)

Y_test.shape
Out[50]: (52, 3)`

Comment: Ok - come back to `categorical_crossentropy` shape. Where this previous error comes from?

Comment: Sure , i'm change `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adadelta')` and when i come this fit line `model.fit(X_train , Y_train , batch_size = batch_size , nb_epoch = nb_epoch ,
           verbose = 1 , validation_data=(X_test , y_test))` again same error omg `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_10 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (52, 1)`

Comment: Dude, there should be Y_test, not y_test

Comment: omg , i'm so happy , epoch steps is working , so thnx so thnxx love u much , `160/164 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9704`

Comment: model.fit get same error -,- train steps is working , but `model.fit(X_test , Y_test , batch_size = batch_size , nb_epoch = nb_epoch ,
           verbose = 1 , validation_data=(X_test , y_test))` getting this error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_10 to have shape (None, 3) but got array with shape (52, 1)`

Comment: You once again have `y_test` instead of `Y_test` :<